# Viewport not working in meta tag

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, viewport, meta, responsive

I want to have max-width of device-width.

My code is here:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5, minimum-scale=0.5; " />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height" />
<meta content="width=640, height=500, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=0.5, user-scalable=0" name="viewport">
```

And my website is here: http://saharservco.net/booksite

I have been testing anything you imagine but didn't work :(
Pay attention that I have used bootstrap and my guess is that it's because of making it responsive and if I didn't use responsiveness the meta tags would work, am I wrong?

Comment: I wonder why you have so many viewports?

Comment: No no, I have used them individually, none of them worked :(

Comment: Did the "standard" Bootstrap Viewport workes `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Unfortunately no :(

Comment: @amateur your viewport is currently commented out

Comment: Before assuming if it would work, try. Let us know. Please post screenshots of what it is  and what you want it to be.

Comment: @RachelGallen I know, I have tested them one by one, so it is stupid to use them all at once. Isn't it?

Comment: @DaniSpringer This is what it shows: http://s2.picofile.com/file/8262252418/1.png and this is what I want it to be shown: http://s1.picofile.com/file/8262252442/2.png. Note that I have made that pic by mspaint :D

Answer (score 1):

I found it, it hasn't been working because I was using desktop browsers and just by lessen width of it, it was changing but not the one that I wanted.

So I used my phone and it worked :)

Comment: Great! You can accept your own answer two days after posting it.

Comment: Thanks for your responses :)